# Socket io emit file and read from buffer

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I emit an event "sendMessage" from client side including file object, inside socket.on("sendMessage") I get <Buffer xx xx xx ... xxxxx more bytes> for file object. How can I read data from buffer? I need for example mimetype, filename..

Comment: without more information to help you debug (i.e. code), I can only suggest you read the [nodejs docs on buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.